# Event Listener in Rails Layout?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question about binding a javascript event listener in a rails 4 layout.  Basically I am in-lining the entire script (https://gist.github.com/dsulli99/5d8309046e5ec1ae55dd), at least for the purpose of getting things running.

The entire script is being in-lined right inside the `<body>` tag of my layout, and I am using the same layout for every single page in my application.

My question is this; it appears that when I click on a link to render any other view using the same layout, that the  does not actually execute.  It will only execute if it is:

1) The first time that a view using that layout is rendered or
2) If I actually click 'reload' on my broswer.

I would expect that since this is part of the body that the entire script would execute with every page load (i.e. if I click on a link constructed using link_to).  Would anybody be able to tell me why the javascript in-lined in the layout itself is not loading with every page implementing that particular layout?  I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Thank you,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have removed it, the default Rails 4 Gemfile includes [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks). It's a JS library that intercepts GET requests and replaces the `<body>` with the result of an XHR to the GET request's location. That means there is [no `window.onload` event](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) for any page after the first.

Your code is relying on `window.onload`, but it will never come. Listen to `page:load` as well, the event fired by Turbolinks after it does its loading.